# how to make custom doughnut Chart from aChartEngine in Android?

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart, donut-chart

I am using aChartEngine library for creating doughnut Chart in my android app, but I am unable set Background Image to my doughnut graph.I have some of the question bellow..
1)How to set Border color to doughnut Graph
2)How to add a label in center of doughnut 
3)And how to set custom Image to doughnut as a Background

My doughnut Activity is

```
public class DonutGraph {
private GraphicalView mChartView2;
static int count = 2;

int[] Mycolors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#FF0000"),Color.parseColor("#000000") };
String[] labels = { "HEADTRAUMA" , "TOTAL"};


public Intent execute(Context context, LinearLayout parent,double values[]) {
    parent.removeAllViews();
    int[] colors = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        colors[i] = Mycolors[i];
    }
    DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setShowLabels(true);
    renderer.setInScroll(true);
    renderer.setStartAngle(90);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);// Disable User Interaction
    renderer.setScale((float) 1.4);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    MultipleCategorySeries categorySeries = new MultipleCategorySeries(
            "HEADTRAUMA");
    categorySeries.add(labels, values);

    mChartView2 = ChartFactory.getDoughnutChartView(context,
            categorySeries, renderer);

    parent.addView(mChartView2);

    return ChartFactory.getDoughnutChartIntent(context, categorySeries,
            renderer, null);
}

protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color : colors) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

    }
    return renderer;
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you solved problem ??

Comment: yes solved...please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917972/how-to-set-image-inside-of-donut-achartengine-graph

Answer (score 0):

For label and background you can use overlay, using another views one below for the background and another on top for the label, all than inside the same ViewGroup with the same metrics, it is easier I guess.

But for the border you will need to change on the class DoughnutChart at char engine source code, more specifically at method draw.

I do not test, but probably this should solve your problem:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
```

after this line:

```
paint.setColor(mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).getColor());
```