# How to set Image inside of Donut-achartEngine Graph?

Tags: android, achartengine, donut-chart

I am using `aChartEngine`Library to make donut graph.But having problem to add image inside of donut Graph. I can set Background Color only , but not get able to set background image inside of donut. Please check image .[image] [image]

Comment: How do you try to do that?

Comment: Have you achieved this ??

Comment: @GOLDEE , check your answer I added it in comment.I have achieved this using `RelativeLayout`instead of `LinearLayout`..

Comment: Is this a question?  Has it been answered?

Comment: @DavidMays I am done with this question using `Relative Layout`..thanks

Comment: This is not a question.  The knowledge that you are using a `RelativeLayout` does little for future readers.  This should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help..

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="170dp" >

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/left_graph_for_head_injury"   //here to draw donut
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="170dp" >
   </LinearLayout>

   <ImageView    //image to place
      android:layout_width="95dp"
      android:layout_height="95dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@drawable/inside_donut_head_injury_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Abhijit, How you achieve right hand chart? I am also trying to display same kind of chart but coudnt find suitable solution. I am using aChartEngine library only. Thanks.